# In Donations upload, if I use PREVIOUS button from second step, and select the csv file again and go to the next step, it throws an error

Tags: import, donations

In Donations upload, if I use PREVIOUS button from second step, and select the csv file again and go to the next step, it throws an error. Please tell me a solution for solve this issue if anyone solved.

Comment: db error:syntax error is showing.

Comment: Which CiviCRM version are you using and which CMS? Can you try on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org? FWIW, I just tried and I don't see an error there.

Comment: @LarsSG CiviCRM 5.58.1,wordpress

Comment: OK, can you try on wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org?

Comment: @LarsSG works fine in wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org.

Comment: Then I'd assume it has been fixed since 5.58.1 and should be fixed for you once upgrade to a more recent version. Only one way to find out though.